# Select particular rows in GQLQueries (JDO) Google app Engine JAVA

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I want to select two columns from the table so is it possible to do that or i have to retrieve whole table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The App Engine data store is not a relational database.

The fundamental unit of data storage are called an entity. You always fetch the whole entity, and not a subset of the entity.

For more information look at the App Engine Datastore API documentation as well as the Low Level API documentation.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/package-summary.html

Comment: That means i cannot select only two or three columns from the Table like        Select name,roll_no from stud

Comment: Actually, that means there is no such thing as a "table", or "columns".  There are entities, which have properties.  If you have some huge properties that you don't want to fetch each time, you could put them in a separate entity.